# Hardware requirements for FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I was exploring the ffmpeg video conversion. Wanted to know what will be the hardware requirements and the time taken to convert a 5gb video file

Answer (score 2):

typically it depends on how much compression you want.  If you want high compression and good quality, it takes forever.  But it is also different between video codecs (and to a small extent, audio codecs, as well), some are faster, some are slower.

Hardware requirements are basically "any cpu" (you might get some speedup with graphics card GPU but ffmpeg doesn't use them heavily/typically yet).  But with stronger hardware, it will convert "faster" as it were.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg can almost run on *everything*.

You can see this:

https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2011-March/000094.html

I don't think there is a standard runtime of coverting 5gb video file. The time may depend on your hardware, the input/output video codec, resolution, format,etc.